# How to Handle Transaction Exception

Tags: database, exception, powershell, transactions

I have a powershell that reads rows of computer information from a database (MS SQL 2008) and stores it into a reader.

```
# Open the database connection
$conn.Open()

# Create and execute the SQL Query

$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql,$conn)

$rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

# Read Computer Information into multidimensional array
$count=0
while ($rdr.read()){
    $sql_output += ,@($rdr.GetValue(0), $rdr.GetValue(1), $rdr.GetValue(2), 
    $rdr.GetValue(3))
    $count=$count + 1
}


# Close the database connection
$conn.Close()    

Write-host Finished reading $count IP addresses from database
```

About 50% of the time, I get an exception

> Exception calling "Read" with "0" argument(s): "Transaction (Process
>   ID 107) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has
>   been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction." At
>   C:\script.ps1:83 char:17
>   + while ($rdr.read <<<< ()){
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

I have about 18,000 computers in the database. When this exception is thrown, it only reads maybe 10,000, it varies from time-to-time.

How to handle the exception so that it reads all 18,000 computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the execution in a `try..catch` block and a loop like this:

```
$conn.Open()
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql,$conn)

do {
  try {
    $rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

    $count=0
    while ($rdr.read()) {
      $sql_output += ,@($rdr.GetValue(0), $rdr.GetValue(1), $rdr.GetValue(2),
                        $rdr.GetValue(3))
      $count=$count + 1
    }

    $transactionComplete = $true
  } catch {
    $transactionComplete = $false
  }
} until ($transactionComplete)

$conn.Close()
```

However, a better approach would be to identify and avoid the deadlock condition (if possible).